# Fake in-app purchases

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app

From Firebase Analytics report I see that for last 2 weeks 9 people had made 10 in-app purchases, but it displays revenue only for one purchase, and there is only one order in the Developer Console.

Is it possible that these purchases have been made through Freedom?

[image]
[image]

Comment: It's really hard to read the console in Russian. Are you sure there are no test purchases?

Comment: Sorry for this) I didn't received answer on russian stackoverflow.
Yes, I'm sure, because there is one succeeded order.

Comment: But if your user is on the test list, the can 'purchase' a real item for free, so to speak

Comment: what is "freedom"?

Comment: @petey The program for bypassing the verification of the Market license (LVL) and for emulating purchases within the application (In-App Billing).

Comment: @Stefan There are only my test and main emails in the alpha-test list. By the way, user can make a purchase only once.

Comment: [This article](https://www.emarketer.com/Article/Rising-Tide-of-In-App-Fraud/1012731) suggests the global fraud rate for IAP is 7.49:1. Meaning for every real purchase, over 7 purchases are fake. So yes it's possible.